# Process MPI data as it's received (Pipe-lining)

Tags: c++, mpi

Say I have an MPI_Send from machine A with a huge message, and on another machine (say, B) it's being received with MPI_Recv (or MPI_isend and MPI_irecv respectively). Currently, B processes the data that's received ONLY after ALL the data has arrived; is there an MPI functionality that allows me to start processing some of the data as I receive it?

Comment: Anything wrong with sending it in smaller chunks?

Comment: @eduffy Wouldn't that mean I have to send and receive many times? In that case, wouldn't the communication overhead be too costy? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You can have a buffer of a minimal size and start sending data through that and consume it as it is received.

You may want to have a look at persistent communication request support of MPI http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node65.htm#Node65 and create some higher level API that suits your application.

All the cases I've seen with pipelining where ad hoc solutions made with `MPI_Send()` / `MPI_Recv()` pairs or `MPI_Sendrecv()`.